# REST for adding throttle tiers?

Tags: api, rest, wso2, tiers

I saw in the user guide a REST for getting a list of all throttling tiers level.

Is there also a REST for adding tiers? Or is adding tiers is available only from the api manager admin ui on https://localhost:9443/carbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't add new tiers from through new REST API. But we have admin dashboard application which provides a UI to manage your tiers. Please refer[1]. It describe the approach of using management console. We will add adding new tiers API to REST API during next releases.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Defining+Throttling+Tiers

Thanks,
Harsha